# Refresh the current page when i click the browser back button(chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I want to refresh the current page when clicking browser back button, it refreshes the same page but the page is refreshed even when I click logout button in the same page. Please give me valuable solution. Thanks in advance

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
  if (window.event) {
    location.reload(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you logout button doesn't manipulate with browser history?

Comment: yes and my expectation is it has to refresh only if i click the browser back button

Answer (score 0):

Friend you can not play with the browser function to go back. But you can add in the function of close session the following code

```
location.reload();
```

You can also place an event that triggers the same function that will reload the page

And if you want to redirect to another url you can use the following code

```
window.location.replace("http//:URL.COM");
```